# Ler um número Par

Tags: java, eclipse

Estou novamente com dúvidas,agora a dúvida é relacionada a exercício sobre 
`Desvio de condicional Simples` usando apenas o comando `IF`

> Após ler um valor inteiro, calcular e apresentar o seu quadrado apenas se o valor lido for par. Caso contrário, o programa deve ser encerrado, sem apresentar nada.

Estou em dúvida em qual será a minha condição do IF que indique que o cálculo só sera realizado se o número informado pelo usuário for par!

Eu declarei três variáveis

1. O Numero que sera digitado
2. A váriavel que ira apresentar o calculo(no caso o numero ao quadrado)
3. A variável para indicar que o valor é par!

E minha segunda dúvida é : Se devo declarar uma variável para indicar que o valor precisa ser par... Ou se apenas indico duas variáveis!

Comment: Utilize o *mod*, ele irá capturar o resto da divisão, por exemplo: `if ( (10 % 2) == 0 )` a expressão quer dizer: *Se o resto da divisão 10/2 for igual à 0, então faça isso. Você também pode utilize `Math.floorMod`

Comment: Se já tem algum código para a resolução do problema, é importante que o coloque na pergunta, dando mais contexto e realçando a sua dificuldade

Comment: Isac..não fiz o código,apenas pensei nas váriaveis!

Comment: Valdeir...no meu caso irei usar o if 10 %2..ja que ainda não vi o método Math!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só precisa de duas variáveis.

Pode fazer assim:

```
int calculo = numero * numero;
if (calculo % 2 == 0) System.out.println(calculo);
// O operador % retorna o resto da divisão. 0 seria numero par, e 1 impar!
// O if não precisa de estar com chaves por conter apenas uma instrução.
```

E pode-se fazer até mesmo com uma variável apenas!

```
if ((numero * numero) % 2 == 0) System.out.println(numero * numero);
```